Spiky deformed mesh when simulating clothing only when rendering
The clothing is deformed inwards, but it does not appear in the viewport, neither in Solid Model nor in Preview Render, it only appears in the real render.
(Preview Render is supposed to show what will appear in the final render, but it doesn't, I don't know why)
How can I fix the warped mesh in the final render?




I was able to fix this by moving the "subdivide" modifier all the way down.
